# Receiving "module itself has errors" error when importing ResizeObserverModule

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm listening to an element's size using the `ResizeObserverModule` from `@ng-web-apis`.  Everything works fine so I don't have any problems with it working.  However the module I import it into highlights as red in VSCode.  When I highlight over it I see the following error

> Appears in the NgModule.imports of DemonstrationComponentsModule, but itself has errors

then says the same about `NgModule.exports` array which really doesn't tell me what the error is seeing that it works perfectly fine.  When I first tried it I imported it into the `AppModule` assuming it would be exposed globally.  After learning we need to import it into the modules we want to use it in I commented it out from the `AppModule` and added it to where I'm using it now.

When I comment it out in the module the error goes away so something is happening as a result of adding it to the module.  The only other time I've run into this error is if I imported something into the `AppModule` that I also have imported in another module that imports into the `AppModule`.

For the sake of keeping with the standard of showing code here's how everything looks.

**Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ResponsiveShellComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ResizeObserverModule,
    PropertyDisplayModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ResizeObserverModule,
    PropertyDisplayModule,
    ResponsiveShellComponent
  ],
  bootstrap:[ResponsiveShellComponent]
}

export class ResponsiveShellModule { }
```

**Component**

```
export class ResponsiveShellComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    //omited for relevance

    WindowSize: windowSize = {width: 0, height: 0};

    public sizeListener(entry: ResizeObserverEntry[]):void{
        this.WindowSize = {
          width: Math.floor(entry[0].contentRect.width),
          height: Math.floor(entry[0].contentRect.height)
        };
    }
}
```

**Template**

```
<section class="shell">
    <article>
        <p>{{WindowSize.width}}</p>
        <p>{{WindowSize.height}}</p>
    </article>
    <iframe
        class="iframeShell"
        #compFrame
        waResizeBox="content-box"
        (waResizeObserver)="sizeListener($any($event))"
    ></iframe>
</section>
```

Does any of this show what might be causing the error?